# How to Install Lubuntu?

Tags: installation, lubuntu

I am having problem with the installation of Lubuntu 11.10 . The problem is in section of "select and install software."

First it was struck at retrieving 636 of 636 and then when there was no progress I restarted the computer then it gave me the following message:

```
Please insert the disc labelled: 'lubuntu 11.10 _Oneric Ocelet_ - release i386(20111011)' in the drive '/media/cdrom' and press enter.
```

I had downloaded an iso image of the Lubuntu 11.10-alternate (592mb) and burned the iso image to the cd.

Comment: This is an old question that's being updated to fit any release of Lubuntu. Therefor it's not off topic. Only new questions about EOL questions are off topic.

Comment: Does this question differ so much from the [How to install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) that we need another question? Is the procedure so different from installing Ubuntu? Or is it just different screenshots?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if at all possible you should download the latest version of [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (13.04) and install that instead. That will have fewer bugs and will work better on hardware old and new.

Lubuntu (yes, the regular Desktop version) should run fine on your PC with that hardware. It will be slow, but it will run. I would wait at least a half an hour before shutting down your PC if you encounter a hang during installation. If you want to check the disk for defects, you can do so by selecting "Check Disk for Defects" at the boot screen.

Lubuntu will certainly run, but the question is whether enough RAM will be available to run the installer. If you keep trying the installation and the PC continually hangs, as in: the mouse is difficult or impossible to move and you can't even get to a tty terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then you may wish to try the [alternate iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Alternate_Installation) as you were attempting. Also, there are several ways to [install without a CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD) that do not require a high level of computer resources.

As a last resort, you can try another distro such as SliTaz if you find that the hardware setup just can't handle the software.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Yes, I was keeping this in mind when I was writing that answer. The advice will apply to any Lubuntu release.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem before. Here are some troubleshooting steps to hopefully fix it:

### Question 1  - Did the ISO image work on a virtual machine?

- Yes: Have you looked for scratches on the CD?

  1. There are scratches: Try burning it to a different CD or a [LiveUSB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
  2. There are no scratches: Check questions 2 and 4.
- No: This is most likely a bad download, try [downloading it from a torrent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu#Torrent) this time.

### Question 2 - Are you on UEFI?

- Yes: Is your BIOS up-to-date?

  1. Yes it is: Try using `wubi` for install.
  2. No it's not: Go to your motherboard manufacturer's website and check for BIOS update utilities.
- No: Refer to below question.

### Question 3 - Are you just dragging and dropping the files from the ISO into the CD?

- Yes: Use the Windows Disk Burner tool.
- No: Good job.

### Question 4 - If you are using a VM for testing, what VM software do you use?

- Other than [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/): Get VirtualBox and see if that works.

If you have any problems, just tell me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Did you download the disk image with BitTorrent or directly from the website?

If latter, did you check the MD5 hash of the disk image before you burned the disk?

Instructions on how to do this are at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) - the MD5 sums are:

- a3d9689f0f63827d8f72a38b5a80767e for lubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso

and

- 6b2ef531916da95982eb9b9de9dcb19e for lubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso.

It's important you do this before you start burn the image on the disk, but you can check the integrity of the disk after burning by booting it up and selecting to check the integrity of it right after the boot up.

It is also important that you try to burn the image as slow as your patience allows you to burn it.

You can follow up the installation process during installing with alternate disk by cycling to other terminals, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd> through <kbd>f8</kbd>. Some parts of the system can take a long time to install and it might look like the system has become unresponsive.

When rebooting, did you still have the installation media in the drive? The error points to the direction that you didn't.

Comment: yes i had checked 
it before burning the iso image

Comment: yes i had checked Mdd5sum before burning the iso image and its was fine and never cared to check after burning it but would be doing it now and could you please tell me one more thing i.e. should i go with lubuntu desktop (i have 256 ram and 20 gb on hard disk ) as its said it should be more then 384 mb here cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release

Answer (score 2):

Why not a newer release of Lubuntu?  I'm sure you have your reasons.  But in case you do want to go with a newer release, as stated in the answer the screens are pretty much the same, they may just look a little different

You can use [ImageBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) under Windows, to burn a bootable CD/DVD,  and [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for a bootable USB under Windows, and Linux.  I would recommend that you create a bootable USB.  For burning a CD/DVD under Ubunut see [How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

> If the CD writing fails, try writing at a slower speed. For better
>   results, try the slowest burn speed reasonably possible. This is the
>   single most likely cause of problems but is much more widely known
>   than Md5sum/SHA error-checking. Slower speeds ensure greater accuracy.
>
> Once you burn the CD/DVD, check it and make sure that it was burned
>   perfectly, by doing a [CDIntegrityCheck](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck?action=show&redirect=CDIntegrityCheck)

First of all why use an alternate CD?  Just download the regular CD.  For [Lubuntu 11.10](http://archive.org/details/Lubuntu11.10DesktopI386Iso), [12.04/12.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PreviousReleases), and [13.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu).  Once downloaded you can either create a CD/DVD, or a bootable USB.  I would recommend that you do an MD5SUM on the ISO downloaded, and try burning on a slow speed, just to be on the safe side.

When done, just change the boot order in your system's BIOS to boot from the desired location.  Once the installation starts, just follow the screens as shown in the images below.  These steps are for all the release mentioned in this answer.  The screens are the same in a way, but look cosmetically different from one release to the next.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Help</sup>

Comment: Oh no! You used the old big red arrows trick!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the Lubuntu Alternate version? It intended for those computers with less than 160Mb of RAM and / or with less than 4.3GB Hard Disk.
If your computer has more RAM and disk space than the above I would recommend giving a try to the 11.10 Desktop version for [32bit](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64bit](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso).
If you have a USB Disk Drive you can also burn the ISO to the USB and boot from it to save a CD.

Comment: @yosslie       I have 256 ram and with enough hard disk.....but its recomebded to have atlest 384 mb by this link http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/

Comment: @karan421 Sorry for the confusion because I read here that RAM requirement is different: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

Comment: @yosslie       thats ok but could you tell me any solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

It could easily be a bad sector on the CD you burned.

If you can access the internet from a different computer, It may be worth burning a new CD and starting the process all over again.

It's a strange situation to find yourself in and I hope this helps.